# With AWS Copilot how to create AWS ALB rules to redirect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-redirect, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-copilot

Is it possible to create ALB rules to redirect using AWS CoPilot? Something like below?

```
http:
  - path: "/*"
    priority: 1
    redirect:
      host: "<redirect-host>"
      path: "/<redirect-path>"
      port: "<redirect-port>"
      protocol: "<redirect-protocol>"
      query: "<redirect-query>"
      statusCode: "<redirect-status-code>"
```

Could not find anything on this regards in the [docs](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/lb-web-service/#http-additional-rules)